# Unable to cast location to ILocation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I am getting a rather weird casting error.  Here is the code:

```
public class OrganizationLocation : IOrganizationLocation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IOrganizationLocation
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Organization : IOrganization
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationLocation> Location { get; set; }

    public ICollection<IOrganizationLocation> Locations
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICollection<IOrganizationLocation>) Location;
        }
    }
}

public interface IOrganization
{
    string Alias { get; }
    ICollection<IOrganizationLocation> Locations { get; }
}
```

now when I try to run this via a service (backend data layer is EF6), the "Location" variable has all the values, however, the "Locations" variable fails to cast.  If I try to do a safe cast, it comes back as null every time.

I'm not understanding why would the cast fail?  It has same fields, both are ICollection Type, so why do I get a HashSet?

The reason why I am doing it this way is because for EF6 framework to be able to treat this class as a table it needs to have a concrete type and a public get/set.  However, I do not wish to expose that, so I use interface instead and then inject the class when the interface is called.  This way I only expose get method and on top of it I only expose interface layers.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Namespace.OrganizationLocation]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Namespace2.IOrganizationLocation]'.

Comment: look up covarance.

Comment: You need to disable EF proxy.  `this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` or remove the `virtual`keyword you put to `Location` property.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I'm not sure if that is the problem, the reason I need the virtual keyword there is so that it maps my tables for me.  I need Location to have a foreign key to Organization.

Comment: If `virtual` keyword is used and proxy not disabled then EF dynamically create new type that derive from Location etc..

Comment: You cannot do this, and here's why: Anyone can now write: `organization.Locations.Add(new SomeOtherLocation())` where `SomeOtherLocation : IOrganizationLocation`. Your list only accepts `OrganizationLocation` objects, but we just added `SomeOtherLocation`. You can *expose* the list of locations, which means it's readonly, by returning `IEnumerable` instead of `ICollection`

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure if that is true, if I try to type what you suggest, it complains and it won't compile.  Notice that my interface only has a getter.  Because it doesn't have a setter, it doesn't allow you to add a new object to the list, or even modify current ones.  The only way to add values or modify it is to create the concrete class and use that.

Comment: Getters and setters are irrelevant here, it's the implementation of ICollection which is a problem. ICollection allows elements to be passed to the object. IEnumerable does not. What compile error are you getting ?

Comment: @Rob It is not a compile error, but a runtime error.  The error is posted in my question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that - and I'm explaining why you get a compile error. ICollection is defined as accepting a T, not only returning it, since it has an add method. This means it is not covariant, and as such you cannot legally cast `ICollection<B>` to `ICollection<A>` even if `B : A` . IEnumerable *is* covariant, as there is not method that takes a T (only returns T). Hence my suggestion to change ICollection to IEnumerable (assuming you never add to the collection). The getters and setters are completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Rob I don't mean to upset you, but I do not get a compile error.  I think you mean runtime error.  Also, that second part makes sense, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry - yes, I did mean runtime error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing the code to the following:

```
public class OrganizationLocation : IOrganizationLocation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IOrganizationLocation
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Organization : IOrganization
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationLocation> Location { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IOrganizationLocation> Locations => Location
}

public interface IOrganization
{
    string Alias { get; }
    IEnumerable<IOrganizationLocation> Locations { get; }
}
```